# Connect capital to city-states quest, do sea routes count?

Tags: civilization-5

When city-states ask for connecting your capital with theirs, do sea routes count? My capital is far away but I do have some coastal cities in between, but I do not know if completing a road from my coastal city (connected by sea to my capital) to the city-state would count.

Comment: Building a Harbor in one of your coastal cities is easy enough.  What makes you think the City-State is rushing to build one too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my experience, it counts so long as the city you connected it to has the city connection symbol.  If that city is blockaded before the road is finished, you'll need to break the blockade before the quest is withdrawn!